# How to find the computer name which send a shutdown command through the network

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, network-programming

I wanna find the computer name which is sending shutdown command to my computer through the network. :) 
please give me an idea..

(I've tryied following code to stop shutdown, but it couldn't do that, because that person can kill process running on my pc. so when he kill the cmd process my program is stoped)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace ExecuteCommand
{
  public class ExecuteCmd
  {
    #region ExecuteCommand Sync and Async
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a shell command synchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">string command</param>
    /// <returns>string, as output of the command.</returns>
    /// 
    public bool x;
        private void Run(bool run,object command)
        {
            if (!run)
                {
                     //create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run, and "/c " as the parameters.
                     //Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows, and then exit.
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
                    // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output. 
                    //This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
                    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    // Do not create the black window.
                    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
                    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                    proc.Start();
                }


                Process[]processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
                {
                    if (theprocess.ProcessName.ToUpper() == "CMD")
                    {
                        number++;
                        //theprocess.Kill();
                    }
                }

                if (number < 50)
                {
                    Run(false,command);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Run(true,command);
                    x = true;
                }
        }

        int number = 0;
        public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
        {
            try
            {
                Run(false, command);

                // Get the output into a string
                //string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                // Display the command output.
                //Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                Run(false, command);
                // Log the exception
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute the command Asynchronously.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="command">string command.</param>
        public void ExecuteCommandAsync(string command)
        {
            try
            {
                //Asynchronously start the Thread to process the Execute command request.
                Thread objThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteCommandSync));
                //Make the thread as background thread.
                objThread.IsBackground = true;
                //Set the Priority of the thread.
                objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
                //Start the thread.
                objThread.Start(command);
            }
            catch (ThreadStartException objException)
            {
                // Log the exception
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException objException)
            {
                // Log the exception
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                // Log the exception
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}


using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ExecuteCommand
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string command = @"for /l %x in (1, 0, 1) do (shutdown -a)";

            ExecuteCmd exe = new ExecuteCmd();
            exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command);

            // Execute the command asynchronously.
            exe.ExecuteCommandAsync(command);

            int number = 0;

            if (exe.x)
            {
                Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
                {
                    if (theprocess.ProcessName.ToUpper() == "CMD")
                    {
                        number++;
                        //theprocess.Kill();
                    }
                }
                if (number < 10)
                {
                    exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command);
                    // Execute the command asynchronously.
                    exe.ExecuteCommandAsync(command);
                }
                else
                {

                    if (!wait(processlist[0]) || !wait(processlist[1]) || !wait(processlist[2]) || !wait(processlist[3]) || !wait(processlist[4]))
                    {
                        exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command);
                        // Execute the command asynchronously.
                        exe.ExecuteCommandAsync(command);
                    }
                }


            }
            else
            {
                exe = new ExecuteCmd();
                exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command);

                // Execute the command asynchronously.
                exe.ExecuteCommandAsync(command);
            }
        }

        private static bool wait(Process p1)
        {
            if (p1.Responding)
            {
                wait(p1);
            }       
            return false;

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have a trojan horse on your PC or something?

Comment: No. no virus running on my pc

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent the shut down when the shutdown command is received.

Comment: And who sends why shutdown commands .....? Explain the deeper sense behind that before we decide to help or not. It still seems awkward to me.

Comment: one of my friend has challenged me to stop that shutdown command and i accept it. 
1) I've tried to use a batch loop to run sutdown -a continuously , but i failed. because he can kill cmd process running on my pc.
2) Then I've tried above code, run a set of cmds. That time he also used a bat loop to kill cmd procees and I failed to stop.

now i'm trying to find another way.. that's why i ask some help. :)

Comment: Install a firewall. ^_^